# Running oracle XE along with glass fish server in NetBeans6.9

Tags: java, glassfish-3, oracle-xe

If oracle.exe is running, then the Glassfish server gives an error and does not start.

I have tried to change the port number of the Glassfish server but this does not help.

I want to use the Oracle 10g database in a Java web application which would require the Glassfish server, so I would be grateful for any solution.

Comment: Error would be helpful...which port did u change?  Admin port 4848? Http port 8080? one of the many others?

Comment: **Just do the solution and that should fix it.**  That's the best answer I can give if you can't be more specific.  It's not fair to expect people to guess your problem.  At least copy and paste the specific error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 7):

It is likely that the Oracle XE's embedded HTTP listener for XML DB (XDB) is having a conflict with the HTTP Port of Glassfish.

You'll need to change the port of either from the default of 8080 to avoid the conflict.

**Changing Oracle XE's HTTP listener port**

This is documented in the [Oracle XE documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/network.htm#BHCBABJB). The following steps have to be performed:

1. `SQLPLUS /NOLOG` (Launch SQLPlus without logging in)
2. `CONNECT SYSTEM/password` (connect as SYSTEM; you'll need to provide the appropriate password)
3. `EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(nnnn);` (Substitute the new port value to *nnnn*).

**Changing the Glassfish instance's HTTP listener port**

This assumes Glassfish 3.1. You can do this using [asadmin](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gkrgf.html#abdjt), by a command similar to the following in asadmin:

`set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-1.port=nnnn`

You'll need to substitute the new port number.

You may also modify the value of the value of the port from the Glassfish domain configuration file at `$GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`. You'll need to edit the entry for "http-listener-1" and change the port from 8080 to another value:

```
<network-listeners>
    <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
</network-listeners>
```

Comment: thanks for help I removed server and installed it again after changing the Http port 8080 now its working........ Thanks.

Comment: @geetika -- please accept (checkmark) the answer if it helped you and is the correct answer.